# Is there a software to convert units for quantities and equations?

Tags: resource-recommendations, units, software, si-units, unit-conversion

For example, Often I end up with a complicated equation that uses non-standard units. In these equations, Temperature is in eV and Magnetic field is in Gauss. I need to convert my equation to another set of non-standard units my friend uses.

Is there a software to help me convert that? Even cgs to SI would be a start. Judging from the comments, it appears as if I do not know how to convert units. Converting a few equations is easy, but it easily gets painful thereafter. My colleague needs them in strangely mixed units so google will not be of help. I was hoping to save time.

I was able to answer my own question using [this algorithm](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel1/32/9079/00403789.pdf?isnumber=9079&prod=JNL&arnumber=403789&arSt=651&ared=661&arAuthor=Novak%2C%20G.S.%2C%20Jr.)

Comment: Knowing how to do unit conversions is a must-have skill to avoid serious errors in your work.

Comment: I totally agree with @CuriousOne, but there's always Google. Just type in the units you want to be converted and an on-screen unit converter pops up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a software recommendation.

Comment: @don_Gunner94: I don't want to pretend that I am not using Google and Excel myself, but I like to do it on paper myself, first, then I crosscheck my calculation once or twice. That way I hope to avoid complete calcification of the "physics center" of my brain. :-)

Comment: I agree, same here. I am a mechanical engineer myself, I love to play around with equations.

Comment: If one gets a long code with dozens of different units (cgs, SI, imperial and what there may be mixed) or if one has to change them often it might save some time and errors to define the given units in terms of target units instead of replacing a 100 variables by hand every time.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can do it with Matlab, Mupad, Maple, Mathematica or even the Smart Math Calculator. Use this method:

[image]

First define your variables with your units of choice, then tell the programm what the conversion factors from the given units to the target units are, for example, if you have km/h and need m/sec define 1km as 1000m and 1sec as h as 60² sec.

If you make a plot or a numerical computation set your target units to 1.

For other methods see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html).